# Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon

Tags: docker, dockerhub

**Material that I used**

- windows 10
- dockerhub (individual),
- installed DockerToolbox-18.06.1 -ce.exe

**situation**

> -I have already made a dockerhub id and I tried to log in from local but that's not working. also, docker build. command Does someone know this error?

**when I tried to log in on local**

```
> Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (error
> during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.38/info:
> open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file
> specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker
> client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate
> that the docker daemon is not running.). Using system default:
> https://index.docker.io/v1/ Login with your Docker ID to push and pull
> images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to
> https://hub.docker.com to create one. Username: taigaaa Password:
> error during connect: Post
> http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.38/auth: open
> //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In
> the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be
> run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker
> daemon is not running.
```

Also in the docker quickstart terminal that's the same thing happen.